# Help with integrating $\int \frac{dx}{1+\sqrt{\tan(x)}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Starting off with subbing $u^2 = \tan(x)$ to remove the square root, I got:

1. $$\int \frac{2u}{(1+u)(1+u^4)} du$$ (Deriving that $\sec^2(x) = 1+u^4$)

Then by applying the partial fractions method, I get:

2. $$\int \frac{-1}{1+u} du + \int \frac{u^3-u^2+u+1}{1+u^4} du$$

The first integral is manageable but for the second one I had to split the individual terms in the numerator into their own fractions to further obtain:

3. $$\int \frac{u^3}{1+u^4}du +\int \frac{u}{1+u^4}du + \int \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^4}du $$

Now, the first two I could solve however it is the last one that I am unable to move forward with;

$$ \int \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^4}du $$

Comment: You can get more legible displayed equations by enclosing them in `$$` instead of `$`.

Comment: I didn't thoroughly check the work, but if the last expression is correct, you could say $1+u^4 = \left(u^{2}-\sqrt{2}u+1\right)\left(u^{2}+\sqrt{2}u+1\right)$ and do some partial fractions.

Comment: $\int \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^4}du
=-\int \frac{d(u+1/u)}{(u+1/u)^2-2}
$

Comment: I've an answer but it is too large....i think that there must be some bounds in the question

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having a "large" answer. If you know how to solve it then go for it. @MathStackexchangeIsVeryBad

Comment: @Accelerator quadratic factoring may work as we could end up with the sum of perfect squares in both fraction denominators, I'll try this out. Thanks!

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsVeryBad the second part to this question does indeed have; for the limits, $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: That's what i said there must be some limits

Comment: @Quanto I am still trying to figure out how you got the RHS. Need some assistance, thanks!

Comment: @ShootingStars i hope all your queries are cleared now

Comment: @ShootingStars wait a moment - your integral is much easier with the limits (a one-liner solution even), why did you not include them in your question?

Comment: @NinadMunshi there are two parts to the question given, the first asked to find an antiderivative of this function, hence my question, and the second asked to substitute the limits

Comment: @ShootingStars you are certainly welcome to try to plug in limits for the second part, but you will find the antiderivative a nightmare to take limits for. It would seem like a big missed learning opportunity for you to not see how to do definite integrals without the need to compute an antiderivative. When you get to the next part, start with the integral instead of the antiderivative and try to come up with the simpler solution. If you need help you can always post another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the other parts of your integrand are simple, we look at the remaining part as requested.  Note that
$$\frac{1-z^2}{1+z^4} = \frac{z^2(z^{-2} - 1)}{z^2(z^{-2} + z^2)} = \frac{-(1 - z^{-2})}{(z + z^{-1})^2 - 2}. \tag{1}$$
Hence the substitution $$v = z + z^{-1}, \quad dv = 1 - z^{-2} \, dz, \tag{2}$$ yields
$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{1-z^2}{1+z^4} \, dz &= -\int \frac{dv}{v^2 - 2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \int \frac{1}{v + \sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{v - \sqrt{2}} \, dv \\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \log \left| \frac{v + \sqrt{2}}{v - \sqrt{2}} \right| + C \\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \log \left| \frac{z^2 + \sqrt{2}z + 1}{z^2 - \sqrt{2}z + 1} \right| + C.
\tag{3} \end{align}$$

Comment: Ahh, now I understand what @Quanto did, thank you so much for explaining.

Answer (score 2):

Here there is slightly  alternative way using a bit of [brute force](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_exhaustion), pushing the decomposition into partial fractions. We can prepare the way for partial fractions by trying to factor the denominator in difference of squares; we can force this like
\begin{align*}1+u^4&=u^4+2u^2-2u^2+1\\
&=(u^4+2u^2+1)-(2u^2)\\
&=(u^2+1)^2-(\sqrt{2}u)^2\\
&=(u^2+1+\sqrt{2}u)(u^2+1-\sqrt{2}u)\\
&=(u^2+\sqrt{2}u+1)(u^2-\sqrt{2}u+1)
\end{align*}

Then we can use partial fraction in order to write
\begin{align*}\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^4}&=\frac{Au+B}{u^2+\sqrt{2}u+1}+\frac{Cu+D}{u^2-\sqrt{2}u+1}\\
&=\frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(2u+\sqrt{2})}{u^2+\sqrt{2}u+1}+\frac{-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(2u-\sqrt{2})}{u^2-\sqrt{2}u+1}.
\end{align*}
Substitution in each denominator reduce calculus to know $\int \frac{1}{t}dt=\ln|t|+K$. Substitution back give the answer
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\ln \left|\frac{u^2+\sqrt{2}u+1}{u^2-\sqrt{2}u+1} \right|+K$$